# React Native - Width and Height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a question about width and height in react native. I set a `View` with width height 50, in my own device (huawei p9 plus) it look okay. Then I change to bigger device (huawei mate9), `View` become bigger. I just want to know is this normal ? or there are some setting can let all devices have same outlook.
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use same outlook in all devices then you have to give percentage value of height and width. Like, first of all you have to import `Dimensions` in you file

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
```

After that *define* **deviceWidth** and **deviceHeight**,

```
var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
var deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
```

And then you use **deviceHeight** and **deviceWidth** for **height** and **width** as below,

```
width : deviceWidth * percentageYouWant / 100
```

Here 'percentageYouWant' is percentage of device width. So which device is you used it will get width from that device.

Answer (score 0):

For same outlook in all the devices, you have to give percentage value of height and width. Like, first  import **Dimensions** in your file

import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

After that `define **deviceWidth** and **deviceHeight**,`

```
var deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
 var deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
```

and then pass this variables in style of view where its required accordingly, as it will take the width and height of your device automatically and adjust your view.
You can also use this variable for customised views(size variations) by applying formula into it.
For eg in styles you can pass width as :

```
width: deviceWidth/2;
```

this above eg. will take the half width of deviceWidth automatically

Answer (score 0):

this is perfectly normal, as it's explained in the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html) "all dimensions in react native are unitless and represent density-independent pixels", so different devices with diffrent size and different DPI will render differently. 
If you want same look and feel, you either use flex, or percentage as explained above